# Java Merge Sort - Don't understand how it perform recursion here

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I dont understand how this code (full code: https://www.online-java.com/0agMvtSA82)

```
 public static void mergeSort(int arr[], int left, int right)       //helper function that creates the sub cases for sorting
    {
        int middle;
        if (left < right) {                             //sort only if the left index is lesser than the right index
            middle = (left + right) / 2;
                
            System.out.println("Left1 " + left + " -- " + right + "----- " + middle);
            mergeSort(arr, left, middle);        //recursion to divide everything into 1 subarray each
            System.out.println("Left2 " + left + " -- " + right + "----- " + middle);


            // System.out.println("Right1 " + left + " -- " + right + "----- " + middle);
             //mergeSort(arr, middle + 1, right);               //
            //System.out.println("Right2 " + left + " -- " + right + "----- " + middle);

           //merge(arr, left, middle, right);                //merge the two subarrays
           //System.out.println("Merge " +Arrays.toString(arr) + " left "+left + " mid "+ middle + " right "+right);
        }
        //System.out.println("Left + right " + left + " -- " + right);
    }
```

was able to log this

```
Welcome to Online IDE!! Happy Coding :)
[5, 1, 8, 2, 9, 3, 7, 4, 12, 11, 66, 83, 29, 56, 23, 56, 90, 11, 10, 20]
Left1 0 -- 19----- 9 (left -- right------- middle)
Left1 0 -- 9----- 4
Left1 0 -- 4----- 2
Left1 0 -- 2----- 1
Left1 0 -- 1----- 0
Left2 0 -- 1----- 0
Left2 0 -- 2----- 1
Left2 0 -- 4----- 2
Left2 0 -- 9----- 4
Left2 0 -- 19----- 9
```

At first it divides everything to a single unit. Then after the method there's an increment back to the whole array again although no method call for that. Anyone know why?

The code was taken from here https://favtutor.com/blogs/sorting-algorithms-java
I did use `Thread.sleep(5000)` but the log is still the same

Full code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a2[] = {5,1,8,2,9,3,7,4,12,11,66,83,29,56,23,56,90,11,10,20};
        //bubbleSort(a);
        //insertionSort(a1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a2));
        mergeSort(a2, 0, a2.length - 1);
    }
        public static void merge(int arr[], int left, int middle, int right){
            
        int low = middle - left + 1;                    //size of the left subarray
        int high = right - middle;                      //size of the right subarray
        //System.out.println(" l: " + low + " h: " + high);
 
        int L[] = new int[low];                             //create the left and right subarray
        int R[] = new int[high];

        int i = 0, j = 0;
 
        for (i = 0; i < low; i++)                               //copy elements into left subarray
        {
            L[i] = arr[left + i];
        }
        for (j = 0; j < high; j++)                              //copy elements into right subarray
        {
            R[j] = arr[middle + 1 + j];
        }
        
 
        int k = left;                                           //get starting index for sort
        i = 0;                                             //reset loop variables before performing merge
        j = 0;

        while (i < low && j < high)                     //merge the left and right subarrays
        {
            if (L[i] <= R[j]) 
            {
                arr[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else 
            {
                arr[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
 
        while (i < low)                             //merge the remaining elements from the left subarray
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
 
        while (j < high)                           //merge the remaining elements from right subarray
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
 

    public static void mergeSort(int arr[], int left, int right)       //helper function that creates the sub cases for sorting
    {
        int middle;
        if (left < right) {                             //sort only if the left index is lesser than the right index
            middle = (left + right) / 2;
                
            System.out.println("Left1 " + left + " -- " + right + "----- " + middle);
            mergeSort(arr, left, middle);        //recursion to divide everything into 1 subarray each
            System.out.println("Left2 " + left + " -- " + right + "----- " + middle);
            // System.out.println("Right1 " + left + " -- " + right + "----- " + middle);
             //mergeSort(arr, middle + 1, right);               //
            //System.out.println("Right2 " + left + " -- " + right + "----- " + middle);

           //merge(arr, left, middle, right);                //merge the two subarrays
           //System.out.println("Merge " +Arrays.toString(arr) + " left "+left + " mid "+ middle + " right "+right);
        }
        //System.out.println("Left + right " + left + " -- " + right);
    }
}
```

Comment: The two prints are the same except for "Left1 " vs "Left 2". The `left`, `right` and `middle` are still with older values.

Comment: It wouldn't. The code you pasted cannot produce that output. It's missing things. For example, it wouldn't even compile, as there's a close brace missing. Paste the whole code that produced this output.

Comment: "There's an increment back to the whole array again although no method call for that. Anyone know why?" Well, it's recursive. It unwinds the stack (i.e. returns from all the recursive calls that were made on the left half of the array) and you end up back with the full array. Then it sorts the right half and, finally, merges the left and right partitions.

Comment: That web page, by the way, is wrong about the time complexity of insertion sort and bubble sort. It says that each has complexity O(n). In fact, both of those algorithms are O(n^2). In addition, its descriptions of the individual algorithms is pretty awkward. You'll get a better explanation at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/.

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to realise is that every execution of `mergeSort` has **its own** set of local variables (like `left`, `right` and `mid`). So when a recursive call returns, the caller still has its own variables that still have the values they had *before* that recursive call was made.

And so it makes sense that when these values are printed *after* the recursive call, it results in the same output as *before* the recursive call. But they will happen in the opposite order as each function returns and the recursion depth diminishes.

Here is a visual representation. Each box represents an execution of the `mergeSort` function. Execution flows from top to bottom. A closing box corresponds to a returning function call.

Note how each box has its own set of `left` and `right`, so whether those are output before making the recursive call or after, those variables will still have the same values and give corresponding output.

```
mergeSort(arr, 0, 19)
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  left == 0, right == 19                                             │
│  output left and right                                              │
│  mergeSort(arr, 0, 9)                                               │
│  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐  │
│  │ left == 0, right == 9                                         │  │
│  │ output left and right                                         │  │
│  │ mergeSort(arr, 0, 4)                                          │  │
│  │  ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐  │  │
│  │  │ left == 0, right == 4                                   │  │  │
│  │  │ output left and right                                   │  │  │
│  │  │ mergeSort(arr, 0, 2)                                    │  │  │
│  │  │  ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐  │  │  │
│  │  │  │ left == 0, right == 2                             │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │ output left and right                             │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │ mergeSort(arr, 0, 1)                              │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────┐  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  │ left == 0, right == 1                       │  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  │ output left and right                       │  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  │ mergeSort(arr, 0, 1)                        │  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  │  ┌───────────────────────────────────────┐  │  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  │  │ left == 0, right == 0                 │  │  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  │  │ (the left < right condition is false) │  │  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  │  └───────────────────────────────────────┘  │  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  │ output left and right                       │  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │  └─────────────────────────────────────────────┘  │  │  │  │
│  │  │  │ output left and right                             │  │  │  │
│  │  │  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘  │  │  │
│  │  │ output left and right                                   │  │  │
│  │  └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘  │  │
│  │ output left and right                                         │  │
│  └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘  │
│ output left and right                                               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Not related to your question: in a correct implementation of merge sort, a second recursive call would be needed to sort the other half of the array, after which those sorted partitions should be merged with a call to `merge`. You can uncomment those lines in your code, to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you! It had been a long time and I read some article in geek for geek and had understand it. For anyone who like, here is the article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-recursion-data-structure-and-algorithm-tutorials/